# ActionSupport - Need help

Tags: visualforce

```
<apex:page controller="testActionSupport">
 <apex:pageblock>
    <apex:form>
            <apex:pageblocksection id="pb">
                <apex:inputfield value="{!cont.lastname}" />
                <apex:inputField id="id3" value="{!cont.gender__c}" >
                    <apex:actionsupport event="onchange" action="{!checkgender}"  />
                </apex:inputField>
                <apex:inputfield id="id4" value="{!cont.Upanayanam__c}" rendered="{!id4rend}" />
                </apex:pageblocksection>
    </apex:form>
  </apex:pageblock>  
  </apex:page>

 Controller code

public class testActionSupport {
public Contact cont{get;set;}
public Boolean id4rend{get;set;}

public testActionSupport(){
    if (cont==null) {cont = new Contact();}
    id4rend=false;
}
public void checkGender(){
    system.debug('inside checkGender');
    if (cont.gender__c == 'Male'){
        id4rend=true;
    }
    else
    {id4rend=false;}

    }

  }
```

OK, here's the steps. First, when I choose the Gender, I'm being forced to enter the name, when I enter the name and then try to toggle around the gender, it works fine....But the additional fields don't show up automatically for the gender I selected previously (unless I come back and change it a second time), how do I get those extra fields displayed in this scenario automatically?

Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try immediate="true" on your actionSupport?

Comment: Yes, I tried that but no luck. the page just refreshes but the additional fields aren't displayed.

Comment: and did you try `rerender=` on the `actionSupport`.  There are three "knobs" at play here - actionRegion (what gets sent to the controller), immediate="true" (bypasses form validations), and rerender= (decides which portions of the page are refreshed).  Some or all of these may be needed. Note you should also add apex:pageMessages in order to see errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<apex:page controller="testActionSupport">
<apex:pageblock>
    <apex:form>
            <apex:pageblocksection id="pb">
                <apex:inputfield value="{!cont.lastname}" />
                <apex:inputField id="id3"  value="{!cont.gender__c}" >
                    <apex:actionsupport event="onchange" action="{!checkgender}"
                                        immediate="true" rerender="pb" />
                </apex:inputField>
                <apex:inputfield id="id4" value="{!cont.Upanayanam__c}" rendered="{!id4rend}" />
                </apex:pageblocksection>
    </apex:form>
  </apex:pageblock>  
 </apex:page>
```

This is how I modified the code. But it's still not working. I'm not using the ACTIONREGION attribute. Should I be using that attribute?

Comment: Thanks Crop1645. It's working now after making the change as you suggested.